# Why is this arrow function not firing, and how to properly call it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why is `someFunction` not being fired in the following snippet? I get an error: `someFunction is not a function`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setInterval = this.setInterval.bind(this);
    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
  }

  setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.someFunction()
    }, 2000);
  }

  someFunction = () => {
    console.log('Some function');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the way you are referring "this" is incorrect. You might wanna go with these options:

Option 1: Explicit binding using **bind()**

```
setInterval = () => {
    setTimeout(this.someFunction.bind(this), 2000);
}
```

Option 2 : Use a fat arrow function

```
setInterval = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.someFunction()
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's technically a scoping issue. `someFunction` does not exist on that `this` what you have in the function passed to `setTimeout`.

Workaround which could work:

```
setInterval = () => {
    const self = this;

    setTimeout(function () {
        self.someFunction()
    }, 2000);
}
```

Or using `() => { }` like the following:

```
setInterval = () => {
    setTimeout(() => this.someFunction(), 2000);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an arrow function inside `setInterval`.

```
setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.someFunction()
    }, 2000);
  }
```

can be

```
setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.someFunction()
    }, 2000);
  }
```

The first snippet fails because the `this` doesn't refer to the correct `this`. There are a lot of questions and answers regarding this on StackOverflow, you can search for them for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> The someFunction is out of scope.
>   You don't need to bind 'this' if you are using arrow functions.

This is the simplest version of your component. Try this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  setInterval = () => {
    console.log('Set Interval');
    setTimeout(this.someFunction, 2000);
  }

  someFunction = () => {
    console.log('Some function');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.setInterval();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}
```

> Don't forget to clear the timer object inside componentWillUnmount.